# Generating a sine wave in Simulink without any standard blocks

Tags: matlab, signals, simulink, trigonometry

I'm trying to generate a sine wave without using any standard blocks available in Simulink. Right now I'm using constants for phase angle and frequency but eventually I want to vary this and hence not using the standard blocks. Here is the Simulink model

[image]

Here is the scope output

[image]

The output is not a sinusoidal wave. **What am I screwing up here?**
I'm using a fixed step auto solver.

Comment: I'm guessing that you are using a too low sampling rate -- hence the distorted waveform. You need to shorten the length of a fixed-length time step in Simulink.

Answer (score 0):

As I'm currently not in the possession of Matlab/Simulink so I can't construct a working example. But I think the best solution for your problem is using a Simulink function block. In this block you can define a Matlab function of your own design and it will allow you to generate any signal you want.
[Mathworks example](https://jp.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/creating-an-example-model-that-uses-a-matlab-function-block.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com)